# Como colocar dois ng-repeat numa mesma view, Ionic/ AngularJs?

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, json, ionic

Tenho que listar dois tipos de arrays interligados numa mesma view. Mas não estou conseguindo listar.

**EDITADO:** *MELHOR EXPLICAÇÃO*

**Tenho quatro tabelas:**

*avaliacao, usuario_app, item_pedidos, cadastra_oferta*

**No primeiro array:** *$scope.avaliacoes = [];*

**Tenho um SQL com o resultado:**

```
  $query="SELECT
   avaliacao.cod_avaliacao,
   avaliacao.cod_cliente,
   avaliacao.cod_fornecedor,
   avaliacao.prato,
   avaliacao.aparencia,
   avaliacao.embalagem,
   avaliacao.entrega,
   avaliacao.atendimento,
   avaliacao.custo_beneficio,
   avaliacao.media,
   avaliacao.observacoes,
   avaliacao.data_hora_pedido,
   avaliacao.iddados_pedido,
   usuario_app.cod_cliente,
   usuario_app.nome,
   usuario_app.pais,
   usuario_app.cep,
   usuario_app.logradouro,
   usuario_app.complemento,
   usuario_app.bairro,
   usuario_app.cidade,
   usuario_app.estado,
   usuario_app.celular,
   usuario_app.numero,
   usuario_app.nascimento,
   item_pedidos.iditens_pedido,
   item_pedidos.tit_pedido,
   item_pedidos.imagem,
   item_pedidos.preco_un,
   item_pedidos.qtd,
   item_pedidos.cod_fornecedor,
   item_pedidos.iddados_pedido,
   cadastra_oferta.cod_oferta,
   cadastra_oferta.cod_fornecedor,
   cadastra_oferta.cod_categoria_com,
   cadastra_oferta.titulo_promocao,
   cadastra_oferta.descricao,
   cadastra_oferta.foto,
   cadastra_oferta.valor_sem_desconto,
   cadastra_oferta.valor_com_desconto,
   cadastra_oferta.desconto,
   cadastra_oferta.validade_oferta,
   cadastra_oferta.igredientes,
   cadastra_oferta.qtd_estoque
FROM
   avaliacao INNER JOIN usuario_app ON avaliacao.cod_cliente = usuario_app.cod_cliente
   INNER JOIN item_pedidos ON avaliacao.iddados_pedido = item_pedidos.iddados_pedido
   INNER JOIN cadastra_oferta ON item_pedidos.tit_pedido = cadastra_oferta.titulo_promocao
WHERE
   avaliacao.cod_fornecedor='$cod_vovo'";
```

**O retorno deste primeiro JSON é este** (um exemplo):

```
[{"cod_avaliacao":"48","cod_cliente":"14","cod_fornecedor":"1","prato":"5","aparencia":"5","embalagem":"2","entrega":"1","atendimento":"5","custo_beneficio":"3","media":"4","observacoes":"sddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd","data_hora_pedido":"2017-04-11 10:34:55","iddados_pedido":"554","nome":"Ramos de S Janones","pais":"","cep":"38300073","logradouro":"Rua 16","complemento":"Apto 2","bairro":"Centro","cidade":"Ituiutaba","estado":"MG","celular":"34999999999","numero":"1511","nascimento":"0000-00-00","iditens_pedido":"457","tit_pedido":"Bacalhau ao molho Sunset","imagem":"http:\/\/vovocooks.com.br\/admin\/vovos\/_lib\/file\/img\/app_img\/1490803982070.jpg","preco_un":"89.70","qtd":"1","cod_oferta":"129","cod_categoria_com":"36","titulo_promocao":"Bacalhau ao molho Sunset","descricao":"Bacalhoada ao molho sunset.","foto":"1490803982070.jpg","valor_sem_desconto":"100.00","valor_com_desconto":"89.70","desconto":"10.30","validade_oferta":"2017-06-28","igredientes":"To inventando.","qtd_estoque":"8"},{"cod_avaliacao":"50","cod_cliente":"14","cod_fornecedor":"1","prato":"5","aparencia":"4","embalagem":"1","entrega":"2","atendimento":"3","custo_beneficio":"2","media":"3","observacoes":"Avalia\u00e7\u00e3o....","data_hora_pedido":"2017-04-15 13:58:08","iddados_pedido":"566","nome":"Ramos de S Janones","pais":"","cep":"38300073","logradouro":"Rua 16","complemento":"Apto 2","bairro":"Centro","cidade":"Ituiutaba","estado":"MG","celular":"34999999999","numero":"1511","nascimento":"0000-00-00","iditens_pedido":"471","tit_pedido":"Bacalhau ao molho Sunset","imagem":"http:\/\/vovocooks.com.br\/admin\/vovos\/_lib\/file\/img\/app_img\/1490803982070.jpg","preco_un":"89.7","qtd":"1","cod_oferta":"129","cod_categoria_com":"36","titulo_promocao":"Bacalhau ao molho Sunset","descricao":"Bacalhoada ao molho sunset.","foto":"1490803982070.jpg","valor_sem_desconto":"100.00","valor_com_desconto":"89.70","desconto":"10.30","validade_oferta":"2017-06-28","igredientes":"To inventando.","qtd_estoque":"8"}]
```

**O segundo array:** $scope.pedidos = [];

**O seguinte SQL:**

```
    $query="SELECT
   avaliacao.cod_avaliacao,
   avaliacao.cod_cliente,
   avaliacao.cod_fornecedor,
   avaliacao.prato,
   avaliacao.aparencia,
   avaliacao.embalagem,
   avaliacao.entrega,
   avaliacao.atendimento,
   avaliacao.custo_beneficio,
   avaliacao.media,
   avaliacao.observacoes,
   avaliacao.data_hora_pedido,
   avaliacao.iddados_pedido,
   item_pedidos.iditens_pedido,
   item_pedidos.tit_pedido,
   item_pedidos.imagem,
   item_pedidos.preco_un,
   item_pedidos.qtd,
   item_pedidos.cod_fornecedor,
   item_pedidos.iddados_pedido
FROM
   avaliacao INNER JOIN item_pedidos ON avaliacao.iddados_pedido = item_pedidos.iddados_pedido
WHERE
   avaliacao.cod_fornecedor='$cod_vovo'";
```

**O retorno deste segundo JSON é:**

```
[{"cod_avaliacao":"48","cod_cliente":"14","cod_fornecedor":"1","prato":"5","aparencia":"5","embalagem":"2","entrega":"1","atendimento":"5","custo_beneficio":"3","media":"4","observacoes":"sddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd","data_hora_pedido":"2017-04-11 10:34:55","iddados_pedido":"554","iditens_pedido":"457","tit_pedido":"Bacalhau ao molho Sunset","imagem":"http:\/\/vovocooks.com.br\/admin\/vovos\/_lib\/file\/img\/app_img\/1490803982070.jpg","preco_un":"89.70","qtd":"1"},{"cod_avaliacao":"48","cod_cliente":"14","cod_fornecedor":"1","prato":"5","aparencia":"5","embalagem":"2","entrega":"1","atendimento":"5","custo_beneficio":"3","media":"4","observacoes":"sddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd","data_hora_pedido":"2017-04-11 10:34:55","iddados_pedido":"554","iditens_pedido":"458","tit_pedido":"Teate edicao","imagem":"http:\/\/vovocooks.com.br\/admin\/vovos\/_lib\/file\/img\/app_img\/1491174503493.jpg","preco_un":"9.00","qtd":"1"},{"cod_avaliacao":"50","cod_cliente":"14","cod_fornecedor":"1","prato":"5","aparencia":"4","embalagem":"1","entrega":"2","atendimento":"3","custo_beneficio":"2","media":"3","observacoes":"Avalia\u00e7\u00e3o....","data_hora_pedido":"2017-04-15 13:58:08","iddados_pedido":"566","iditens_pedido":"470","tit_pedido":"Pizza Grande de Calabresa   Coca-Cola 2 Litros!!!","imagem":"http:\/\/vovocooks.com.br\/admin\/vovos\/_lib\/file\/img\/app_img\/Pizza Calabresa.jpeg","preco_un":"29","qtd":"1"},{"cod_avaliacao":"50","cod_cliente":"14","cod_fornecedor":"1","prato":"5","aparencia":"4","embalagem":"1","entrega":"2","atendimento":"3","custo_beneficio":"2","media":"3","observacoes":"Avalia\u00e7\u00e3o....","data_hora_pedido":"2017-04-15 13:58:08","iddados_pedido":"566","iditens_pedido":"471","tit_pedido":"Bacalhau ao molho Sunset","imagem":"http:\/\/vovocooks.com.br\/admin\/vovos\/_lib\/file\/img\/app_img\/1490803982070.jpg","preco_un":"89.7","qtd":"1"}]
```

**O que quero é na view, tem na tabela avaliacao o campo iddados_pedido que, pode conter mais de um item. E esses itens serem listados.**

Não sei se estou fazendo corretamente, criando dois JSON. Ou se há alternativa melhor.

**Agora o projeto:**

Primeiramente, minha view:

```
 <ion-view title="avaliações">

    <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">

        <ion-refresher pulling-text="Puxe para atualizar..." on-refresh="getavaliacoes()"></ion-refresher>


        <div>
            <center>
                <h4>Esta Vovó Cozinheira possui 0{{quantida_avaliacoes}} avaliações.</h4>
            </center>
        </div>

        <div ng-repeat="avalia in avaliacoes | unique: 'cod_avaliacao'">



            <div class="card">


                <h5 id="avaliaEs-heading30" style="color:#000000;">Avaliado por: {{avalia.nome}}</h5> Em: {{avalia.data_hora_pedido | date:"dd/MM/yyyy 'às' h:mma"}}

                <div class="item item-body">
                    <ion-list ng-repeat="produtos in pedidos track by $index">
                        <ion-item class="item-avatar royal">
                            <img src="{{produtos.imagem}}">  
                            <h2royal>{{produtos.tit_pedido}}</h2royal>
                        </ion-item>                        
                    </ion-list>
                </div>


                <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 5.99432px;"></div>


                <h5 id="avaliaEs-heading19" style="color:#000000;">Delícia: <span class="stars alignright">
          <span ng-style="{ 'width': getStars(avalia.prato) }"></span> </h5>

                <h5 id="avaliaEs-heading27" style="color:#000000;">Aparência: <span class="stars alignright">
          <span ng-style="{ 'width': getStars(avalia.aparencia) }"></span></h5>

                <h5 id="avaliaEs-heading27" style="color:#000000;">Atendimento: <span class="stars alignright">
          <span ng-style="{ 'width': getStars(avalia.atendimento) }"></span></h5>

                <h5 id="avaliaEs-heading29" style="color:#000000;">Custo x Benefício <span class="stars alignright">
          <span ng-style="{ 'width': getStars(avalia.custo_beneficio) }"></span></h5>

                <h5 id="avaliaEs-heading28" style="color:#000000;">Embalagem <span class="stars alignright">
          <span ng-style="{ 'width': getStars(avalia.embalagem) }"></span></h5>

                <h5 id="avaliaEs-heading29" style="color:#000000;">Prazo de Entrega <span class="stars alignright">
          <span ng-style="{ 'width': getStars(avalia.entrega) }"></span></h5>


                <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 15.9943px;"></div>

                <div class="card">
                    <p style="white-space:normal;">
                        <b>Avaliação: </b> {{avalia.observacoes}}
                    </p>
                </div>



                <h5 id="avaliaEs-heading29" style="color:#000000;">Média: <span class="stars alignright">
                    <span ng-style="{ 'width': getStars(avalia.media) }"></span> </h5>

                </h5>
                </h5>
                </h5>
                </h5>
                </h5>
                </h5>
                </h5>


            </div>



        </div>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Aqui tenho dois ng-repeat:**

**O primeiro** é o principal:

```
        <div ng-repeat="avalia in avaliacoes | unique: 'cod_avaliacao'">
```

**O segundo** é o que pretendo interligar e listar os itens onde os itens de campo *iddados_pedido = aos campos de iddados_pedido da tabela avaliações* seja igual a tabela itens_pedido, como explicado no começo...:

```
<div class="item item-body">
                <ion-list ng-repeat="produtos in pedidos track by $index">
                    <ion-item class="item-avatar royal">
                        <img src="{{produtos.imagem}}">  
                        <h2royal>{{produtos.tit_pedido}}</h2royal>
                    </ion-item>                        
                </ion-list>
            </div>
```

Fiz duas chamadas em **meus controllers**, um para avaliações e outro para pedidos *(Ambos bem parecidos)*:

```
     // LISTA PRODUTOS    
            $scope.avaliacoes = [];
            $scope.getavaliacoes = function () {
                $scope.avaliacoes = [];
                $ionicLoading.show();
                var url = "?cod_vovo=" + $scope.cod_vovo;
                console.log(url);
                var encodedurl = encodeURI(url);


                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        var responseishere = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        if (responseishere == "error") {
                            $scope.nothing = 1;
                            $ionicLoading.hide();
                            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                        } else {
                            $ionicLoading.hide();
                            var myobj = JSON.parse(responseishere);
                            for (var i = 0; i < myobj.length; i++) {
                                $scope.avaliacoes.push(myobj[i]);
                            }
                            var len = myobj.length;
                            //                            if (len !== '0') {
                            $scope.quantida_avaliacoes = len;
                            window.localStorage.setItem("qtd_avalia", $scope.quantida_avaliacoes);
                            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                        }

                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/apis/api_listagem/lista_avalia_novo.php" + encodedurl, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            };
            $scope.getavaliacoes();
            // FIM LISTA PRODUTOS



        // LISTA OS ITENS PEDIDOS    
            $scope.pedidos = [];
            $scope.getpedidos = function () {
                $scope.pedidos = [];
                console.log("Entrou em pedidos");
                $ionicLoading.show();

                $scope.cod_vovo = window.localStorage.getItem("cod_vovo_pedido");


                var url = "?cod_vovo=" + $scope.cod_vovo;
                var encodedurl = encodeURI(url);
//                console.log(url);

                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        var responseishere = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        if (responseishere == "error") {
                            $scope.nothing = 1;
                            $ionicLoading.hide();
                            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                        } else {
                            $ionicLoading.hide();
                            var myobj = JSON.parse(responseishere);
                            for (var i = 0; i < myobj.length; i++) {
                                $scope.avaliacoes.push(myobj[i]);
                            }                          
                            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                        }

                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/apis/api_listagem/lista_avaliacoes_detalhe.php" + encodedurl, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
            $scope.getpedidos();
```

Mas me retorna apenas o primeiro ng-repeat.

O que posso estar fazendo de errado? Ou há outra forma?

Comment: Você está apanhado mais para o angular & orientação à objetos do que para os própios ng-views. Duas sugestões: 1. De uma olhada no angular e seus componentes com calma e tente trabalhar com objetos. 2. não faça ajax na mão, use o ciclo de vida do angular e aproveite o móduto $http dele que já encapsula a chamada em uma promise (conceito extremamente importante para se trabalhar com o angular).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    var responseishere = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    if (responseishere == "error") {
                        $scope.nothing = 1;
                        $ionicLoading.hide();
                        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                    } else {
                        $ionicLoading.hide();
                        var myobj = JSON.parse(responseishere);
                        for (var i = 0; i < myobj.length; i++) {
                            //$scope.avaliacoes.push(myobj[i]);
                              $scope.pedidos.push(myobj[i]);
                        }                          
                        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                    }

                }
            };
```

Você não está colocando os dados no array pedido.
E acho que vc pode mudar essa parte toda usando apenas o $http.get do angular, vai ficar algo tipo assim:

```
    $http.get("http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/apis/api_listagem/lista_avaliacoes_detalhe.php" + encodedurl).then(function(data){ 
   /* mexe com seu array aqui */
}).catch(function(err){
    /* erro */
});
```

Comment: Obrigado @Douglas, funcionou perfeito. E que falta de atenção a minha. Valeu demais!

Comment: Tranquilo ^^ , só tenta dar uma olhada no $http do angular pra vc evitar fazer tudo isso, pra deixar o código mais leve e legível, se cuida!!